# wxPython with long running process freeze the animated gif

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython, animated-gif

I'm trying to run python long processes, but I need to say to the user that is not frozen showing an animated gif.

My issue is I have 3 or 4 long processes and to run the second, it depends the result from the first, so this make not possible to run those processes in threads.
Is there some way to do this?
In my example I have only two process just for illustrate the way that I'm doing this.

```py
import wx
from wx.adv import Animation, AnimationCtrl
import speedtest
import socket

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        # ensure the parent's __init__ is called
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

        # create a panel in the frame
        self.pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        self.pnl.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(81, 87, 129))

        # and put some text with a larger bold font on it
        st = wx.StaticText(self.pnl, label="Speed Test", pos=(200,10))
        font = st.GetFont()
        font.PointSize = 14
        font = font.Bold()
        st.SetForegroundColour("white")
        st.SetFont(font)

        self.anim = Animation('pictures/wait.gif')
        self.ctrl = AnimationCtrl(self.pnl, -1, self.anim)
        self.ctrl.SetPosition((70,50))

    def AnimeControl(self, status):
        if status:
            self.ctrl.Play()
        else:
            self.ctrl.Stop()

class NetworkChecks():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def resolve_dns(self, host):
        try:
            data = socket.gethostbyname_ex(host)
            if "error" in data:
                return False
        except Exception, e:
            print "resolve_dns: ", e
            return False
        return data

    def speed_test(self):
        try:
            servers = []
            threads = None
            st = speedtest.Speedtest()
            st.get_servers(servers)
            st.get_best_server()
            st.download(threads=threads)
            st.upload(threads=threads)
            st.results.share()
            return st.results.dict()
        except Exception, e:
            print "speed_test: ", e
            return False 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frm = MainFrame(None, title='NDT', size=(480, 330), style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE | wx.MINIMIZE_BOX)
    frm.AnimeControl(True)
    frm.Show()

    wx.Yield()

    dns_name = NetworkChecks().resolve_dns('dns.google')

    if dns_name != False:
        speed_results = NetworkChecks().speed_test()
        if speed_results != False:
            print "Speed test results:"
            print "Internet ip: " + speed_results['client']['ip']
            print "Service ip : " +  speed_results['client']['isp']
            print "Download tx: " + '{0:.4g}'.format(speed_results['download'] / 1000000) + " Mbps"
            print "Upload tx  : " + '{0:.4g}'.format(speed_results['upload'] / 1000000) + " Mbps"
        else:
            print "Was not possible to test the internet link speed "
    frm.AnimeControl(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Can you post all the assets so I can reproduce your example? Can you overlay an opaque loading-animation which runs on a separate thread?  Then at the conclusion of final-process-4, terminate the loading-animation thread.

Comment: The Gif: tiny.cc/uf8ibz

Answer (score 0):

You should start your long-running processes in a separate thread, not in the main GUI one. See here for some ideas and implementations:

https://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

The use of wx.CallAfter and wx.PostEvent is your best bet to keep the GUI responsive while other threads and processes go along doing their things.

Comment: I've tried the 3 ways without success. Maybe because I need the results from the function to start another.

Comment: What I meant is: 1. Create the GUI. 2. From the GUI start a separate thread. 3. From this thread spawn a new process that calls your “resolve_dns”and then calls “speed_test”. 4. In the thread you started, just sit and wait until the processes have finished. 5. When they’re finished, from the thread use wx.CallAfter to stop the animation.

Comment: Hello @Infinity77, the animation is still freezing. This is my code: https://pastebin.com/Bd5dsHvc

Comment: it's freezing b/c you call start() and then immediately call join()

Comment: Thanks, but all examples that I saw, the join() is called immediately after start(), do you have some tip?